# Разбор SOAP ответа

Tags: php, xml, soap

Имеется такой SOAP запрос:

```
$UserID = 1;
$Password = 2;
$PartNumber = array(RS999297,RS999124);
$client = new SoapClient("URL?wsdl");
foreach($PartNumber as $key=>$value) { 
      $api = $client->GetPartQty(array('UserID'=>$UserID,
                                       'Password'=>$Password,
                                       'PartNumber'=>$value));
    print_r ($api->GetPartQtyResult);
}
```

Такой ответ сервера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как получить данные только из "ТЭГа" к примеру "qty"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле нужно пробовать разные варианты. Что-то получается, что-то отбрасывается.

Например можно воспользоваться `simplexml_load_string` -  Интерпретирует строку с XML в объект [[Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.simplexml-load-string.php)]

И дальше уже можно добраться до нужного элемента через родителей, используя `->` для объектов

К примеру:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://nbrb.by/Services/ExRates.asmx?WSDL", array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 0 ));
$result = $client->CurrenciesRefDaily()->CurrenciesRefDailyResult->any;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

echo 'Result xml: '. $result;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml->NewDataSet->DailyCurrenciesRef->Cur_QuotName);
echo '</pre>';
```

самый последний `print_r` выведет `1 албанский лек`

или используя `domDocument` - Представляет все содержимое HTML или XML документа; служит в качестве корня дерева документа. [Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php)

И конкретно его метод `loadXML` - Загрузка XML из строки
 Далее можно будет работать методами `getElementsByTagName` и прочими, к примеру:

```
$xml = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<books>
 <book>Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture</book>
 <book>Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Software Design</book>
 <book>Clean Code</book>
</books>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('book');
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```